GnuCash SQL - Cash based PNL (Query or bulk unpost)
I am using GnuCash with a SQLite based file and am entering invoices and bills, recording payments as they are made.
In accrual accounting (which GnuCash uses) the full amount of the invoice/bill is tracked as income/expense on the post date.
I want to generate a cash based PNL or cash flow, reporting on the total spent per expense account.
Within accrual accounting, the entire bill amount is recorded as an expense, and the cash flow report will just record a cash flow to the A/P account, I want to see the amount paid by expense account of the bill.
I am open to running a SQL query against the file (I am using SQLite as the file backend) whether to query or to bulk unpost the invoices/bills, however I am looking for help to see how to link the payments (which are recorded against the A/P account) to the (partially) paid bill line expense account.
Any leads?

You are on the right track. Design your SQL report.

That is what I am looking for insight, how do I link the payments to the bills, what are the tables & columns which record which payment was made to which bill.

GnuCash doesn't use neither accrual nor cash-based system, it's double-entry accounting system - a completely orthogonal dimension.
Whether to use accrual or cash-based is up to you - if you use accounts payable/receivable then you're using accrual-based system. If your income and expenses accounts directly affect the assets/equity accounts then you're using a cash-based system.
You might be confusing "cash-based PNL" with "cashflow report" (see section 10.3.5.1), which is something that would have meaning when in accrual-based accounting.

As you say, if AP/AR is used it is accrual accounting. GnuCash Business features use AP/AR (ie accrual accounting), otherwise it is not used (ie cash accounting).

@flywire it's up to you which accounts to use, really. Not sure what "GnuCash Business" means in this context. Anyway, to the point of your question, if you're using accrual-based accounting then "cash-based PNL" has no meaning from accounting perspective. You'd want a cash-flow report (and AFAIK GnuCash has some built-in ones, but one can design their own too).

I disagree because GnuCash ties AP/AR to Business features. Anyway, I use cash-based PNL for my business but I can't in GnuCash. Sure, when hell freezes over you can design your own GnuCash custom reports (check history).

I do use AP/AR to track how much I still owe the vendors and how much the customers still owe, I want to see a cash flow report showing which underlying expense was paid by the amount transferred from an asset account to the AP account.
